# How can I modify the input type of the Rails datetime_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, datetime-select

I am using the Rails helper `datetime_select` in one of my forms.  I currently have a requirement to change the dropdowns for `day`, `year`, `hour`, and `minute` to be textboxes with validation.  Is there a way I can specify that I want textboxes for these fields?  Or possibly a different helper that will do what I need?

here is my usage:

```
datetime_select(:campaign, :start_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year, :hour, :minute])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about rolling your own simple helper, like

```
def datetime_text_fields(object_name, method)
  html = text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(3i)]", Date.today.day.to_s, :length => 2)
  html << select_month(Date.today, :field_name => "#{object_name}[#{method}(2i)]")
  html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(1i)]", Date.today.year.to_s, :length => 4)
  html << " "
  html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(4i)]", Time.now.hour.to_s, :length => 2)
  html << ":"
  html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(5i)]", Time.now.min.to_s, :length => 2)
end
```

Feel free to add more formatting stuff/separators etc. but it basically returns to correct field names for rails to be identified as DateTime. Rails expects fields named like `date(1i)`, 1i = year, 2i = month etc.

Honestly I didn't test it or anything, but the output in console looked pretty convincing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not roll your own, just name the input fields in the same exact way that the date picker helper does, and you get all the back-end benefits while rolling a custom front-end. Or use the `:order` to have your date picker give the month selection, and use some javascript magic for the other input.

You can use a jquery datepicker and populate hidden fields with the same naming convention as the rails datepicker.