# Rails - date input format?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way in rails to override default date input in form? 
In html form I get date input as drop down menu. The thing is for year it only shows year from 2008 to 2018. How can I make it let me enter any year I want, but keep month and day as dropbox?
I tried in html form use type="date", but nothing changes.

What is the best way to modify date input format in rails (and html/javascript if it needs to be changed there too)?

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231772/how-can-i-modify-the-input-type-of-the-rails-datetime-select-helper) can help you to develope your own helper.

Answer (score 1):

Your could write your own helper:

```
def date_year_text_field(object_name, method)
  html = select_day(Date.today, :field_name => "#{object_name}[#{method}(3i)]")
  html << select_month(Date.today, :field_name => "#{object_name}[#{method}(2i)]")
  html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(1i)]", Date.today.year.to_s, :length => 4)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `start_year` and `end_year` option. By default the range is `current_year - 5` and `current_year + 5`

```
date_select("post", "updated_on", start_year: 1995, end_year: 2013)
```

Read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for more options